# Zbar lib on iOS on TabItem in XE6

Tags: ios, tabitem, zbar

In a Delphi XE 6 environment, I can compile the Zbar lib into an iOS app. It worked fine. However, this one is placed on a TabItem. When leave that tab, the Reading frame is still on the top of the app window. I am guessing it is related to its creation, ZBarCode := TZBarCode.Create; This one is not allowed for create with a parent handle. What shall I do?

Another related question. In the same app, I have a standard sharesheet action. If I start the app, and use the barcode reader, it works fine. Then I take a photo with sharesheet action, the photo part is OK as well. Now it I go back to bar code reader, it refuse to recognise the code although there is a clear image in the reading frame. It seem the Zbar lib can not pick up the real time image. Any comments ?

Comment: ZBar does work in realtime, it sounds as though the sharesheet is not giving back the video feed.

Comment: Feel the same. As no further details from Delphi side, no idea what sharesheet has done, how to release its control of the video feed. Maybe should use the camera component? But it involves more coding.

Comment: Can you send an event to instruct the Zbar views to set up again? (Not sure how to do this in Delphi, but easy enough in native Objc)

Comment: Thanks Jasper for the comment, Delphi wrapped the Zbar SDK. What is the native ObjC code, I may find the similar event if I know the object hierarchy in C.

Comment: There's plenty of sample apps out there for plain old Objc. Maybe this one? https://github.com/a2n/zbar-iphone-example

Comment: Oooh , that's too much to absorb. Any single line hint, pls? Just want to try a couple of possible working line.